# How can I load a reference from a local variable at an index which is unknown at compile time?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

As far as I understood the JVM bytecode specification, 
`aload index` pushes a reference found at `index` onto the current stackframe. In my case, I need to `aload` a reference found at an index which is stored in a local variable - something like this: `aload (iload 2)`.

(How) Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. Otherwise verifier would not be able to prove the correctness of the bytecode.

To access values by index use array objects with the corresponding bytecodes, e.g. `aaload`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dedicated bytecode instruction to perform this kind of selector, so if you want to load a local variable based on the contents of another variable, you have to code this operation yourself, e.g.

```
// pick #1 or #2 based on #0 in [0..1]
 0: iload_0
 1: ifne          8
 4: aload_1
 5: goto          9
 8: aload_2
 9: // value is now on the stack, ready for use
```

or

```
// pick #1, #2, or #3 based on #0 in [0..2]
 0: iload_0
 1: ifne          8
 4: aload_1
 5: goto          18
 8: iload_0
 9: iconst_1
10: if_icmpne     17
13: aload_2
14: goto          18
17: aload_3
18:  // value is now on the stack, ready for use
```

or, to have a variant that scales with higher numbers of variables:

```
// pick #1, #2, or #3 based on #0 in [0..2]
 0: iload_0
 1: tableswitch   { // 0 to 2
               0: 28
               1: 32
               2: 36
         default: 36
    }
28: aload_1
29: goto          37
32: aload_2
33: goto          37
36: aload_3
37: // value is now on the stack, ready for use
```

The last variant has been generated with the ASM library and the following helper method, calling it like `loadDynamic(…, 0, 1, 3);`

```
/**
 * Load variable #(firstChoice + value(#selector))
 */
public static void loadDynamic(
              MethodVisitor target, int selector, int firstChoice, int numChoices) {
    Label[] labels = new Label[numChoices];
    for(int ix = 0; ix < numChoices; ix++) labels[ix] = new Label();
    Label end = new Label();
    target.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ILOAD, selector);
    target.visitTableSwitchInsn(0, numChoices - 1, labels[numChoices - 1], labels);
    target.visitLabel(labels[0]);
    target.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, firstChoice);
    for(int ix = 1; ix < numChoices; ix++) {
        target.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, end);
        target.visitLabel(labels[ix]);
        target.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, firstChoice + ix);
    }
    target.visitLabel(end); // choosen value is now on the stack
}
```

Obviously, array based code using the intrinsic index based access instructions is much simpler and more efficient in most cases.